# Problems connecting firebird with .ib database (Interbase)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, interbase, firebird-3.0

I have a problem and I can not connect to my .IB (Interbase) database with firebird.

The case is that I have downloaded firebird 3.0 and I do not know how to connect to the interbase database I have.

Do I need any more software?

Normally in my previous configuration I had the Interbase server and used the Ibconsole for the theme of the tables and so on.

Is there any way to do this with firebird?

Comment: What is a "theme of the tables"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird cannot open Interbase database. The only exception is Interbase 6 databases (and maybe some older versions).

Firebird was forked +/- 18 years ago from Interbase 6 (which was opensourced for a short time), since then it has diverged, and Firebird can no longer read Interbase databases, nor can Interbase - as far as I am aware - read Firebird databases more recent than Firebird 1 (or maybe 1.5); and it is entirely possible that ability has been removed in recent Interbase versions (just like Firebird 3 cannot read databases from earlier Firebird versions).

The only real option you have is to recreate the database structure in a new Firebird database, and then move the data using a datapump tool, or a custom script.